# Angular 4 router animation between 3 routes

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations, angular4-router

Lets's say, that I have 3 different routes, A,B and C and you can navigate from any route to another.
The display of the 3 routes visually would look like a [slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDPdA.jpg).

I would like to  create a slide animation for all the possible route change combinations.
From B->C, C->B, B->C, C->B it's trivial.
But what if I want to create an animation between A->C and C->A, which should look like it's sliding through B.

What would be the best practice for this?